# Laravel: How to aliases a column name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Imagine that exists a `User` model instance with below properties:

```
User {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Alexandre',
  email: 'alexandre@email.com'
}
```

And in the view I want to automatically print each column alias + value by using a `@foreach` statement, for example:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($user as $attribute)
        <li>{{ $attribute->column_alias }}: {{ $attribute->value }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Would work like the Validator attributes aliasing. The output result should be:

- Identification: 1
- Name: Alexandre
- E-mail address: alexandre@email.com

There is some way to do this?

Comment: I wouldn't bog down your user model with view logic.   I think you'll find very few cases where printing out every attribute like this will be useful.  If you do find yourself in those cases, maybe use language files to translate 'email' to 'E-mail Address'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `$someModel->toArray()` (or `->getAttributes()`, which will hide sensitive data such as passwords) to get the underlying data array. That way, you can print the column names and their values:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($user->toArray() as $key => $attribute)
        <li>{{ $key }}: {{ $attribute }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

But your keys will say e.g. "id", "name", etc., and not a longer word. I would suggest putting that in a translation file. Just as an example:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($user->toArray() as $key => $attribute)
        <li>{{ __('user-model-keys.'.$key) }}: {{ $attribute }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

`resources/lang` contains a folder for every language you want your application in. Every file in there contains your translations as a returned array. So if you want to translate "id" as "Identification", and your language is English, then given the above code you create a file `resources/lang/en/user-model-keys.php` and put this inside:

```
<?php
return [
    'id' => 'Identification'
];
```

Now, `__('user-model-keys.id')` will translate "id" to "Identification".

You can read more about localisation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization

Comment: can you guide me into the translation file approach?

Comment: Sure, updated my answer with a little more info. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: yeah! this fit the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

In your model add this

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $alias = [
    'name' => 'user name',
    'email' => 'User email',
    'other property' => ' property alias'
];

/**
 * @param $attribute
 * @return string
 */
public function getAttributeAlias($attribute) {
    return $this->alias[$attribute] ?: '';
}
```

then you can use

```
<ul>
    @foreach($user->getAttributes() as $attribute => $value)
        <li>{{ $user->getAttributeAlias($attribute) }}: {{ $value }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

For make it out of model you can add config file like this `alias.config`

```
return [
    'user' => [
        'name' => 'User name',
        'email' => 'User Email',
        'other property' => 'property alias'
    ],
    'other model' => [
         'other property' => 'property alias'
    ]
];
```

Usage

```
<li>{{ config('alias.user.' . $attribute, '')) }}: {{ $value }}
```

Comment: doesn't fit the question. in this above, the output will be the column's real name.

Comment: i need to alias the column's real name like Validator does: `'name' => 'User name', email' => 'E-mail address'`

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi See my updated answer that is you need??

Comment: nice approach, maybe I will be using it.

Comment: Let me know if I help you?

Comment: Upvote gave. would be nice either if this view logic was placed outside the model definition.

Comment: You can add this part in some config file(for example alias.config), and make global helper function

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi see my new updated answer where alias out is model